# splitter ??= new graphemer_1.default(); Error while using Eslint lint fix

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I have used following command in package.json file under scripts

"lint": "eslint . -c .eslintrc.json --ext .ts",
"lint:fix": "eslint . -c .eslintrc.json --ext .ts --fix"

While committing to git its giving me this error

```
splitter ??= new graphemer_1.default();
         ^^^
```

I made few changes in package json script but its giving me same error

Comment: which version of `eslint` are you using ?

Comment: using "eslint": "^8.51.0"

Answer (score 0):

To use the [Nullish coalescing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) `??=` operator, you need to set the `ecmaVersion` to at least `2021` or `latest`.

```
"parserOptions":
{
  "ecmaVersion": 'latest'
}
```